# Introduction to folders of haskell platform?

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

I am stressed from many folders included in haskell platform

because i do not know the structure of libraries, can not find and read that needed for studying or programming somethings new.

anythings are welcome

help me :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for here. Are you looking for the [Haskell Platform documentation](http://lambda.haskell.org/platform/doc/current/start.html)? There's a [list of all the modules](http://lambda.haskell.org/platform/doc/current/index.html) if that's what you mean by "folders".

Comment: If you want to find a function to do something, you can use the [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) search engine to discover it.

Comment: I guess what we're saying is that the (online) documentation is a better way of finding out about the contents of the Haskell platform than trying to browse the contents of the installation on your hard drive. (The installation is organised by package first, rather than by module, so there's no obvious way to know where something will be.)

Comment: i want to see offline. and additionally to know how 'import' command in .hs automatically load genuine module

Comment: @AndrewC which books or things are good for solution?

Comment: The book [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) has a printed edition you can buy, as has [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/). Both are aimed at people with some programming experience. The book I learned functional programming from was Bird & Wadler's Introduction to Functional Programming. The [second edition](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Functional-Programming-Haskell-Edition/dp/0134843460/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1369078203&sr=8-2&keywords=bird+wadler) is specifically about Haskell.

Comment: If you just want to see the documentation offline, open up doc/html/index.html in your Haskell Platform directory: that will show you the GHC users guide and the documentation for the libraries. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @yatima2975 Oh, Thanks. but no. i want to see .hs, .lkshw or so which are really loaded by "import" in script.

Comment: If you go into the libraries documentation and open a specific package, there is a link named 'Source' on the right-hand side of the page. That will take you the haskell file the documentation was produced from. That should give you lots of stuff to read!

Comment: @yatima2975 Yup, there are libs. how to read those files having extension; .hi, .dyn_hi, p_hi??

Comment: @yatima2975 i found this http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.8.3/html/users_guide/separate-compilation.html
Thanks very much!

Comment: You don't have to read the .hi files, those are the compiled interface files from the .hs files. I use Haskell quite a lot, and never look at them! In any case, I'm glad you seem to have to found what you were looking for!

Comment: @yatima2975 Yup! i got it. i appreciate your kindness ;).

Comment: @김진성 It's much easier to look things up on [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) and read the documentation there.